# How would I lock a stored procedure that is executing and alter the table that the stored procedure returns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, jdbc, rdbms

I have a table as follows:

```
id    status
--    ------
1     pass
1     fail
1     pass
1     na
1     na
```

Also, I have a stored procedure that returns a table with top 100 records having status as 'na'. The stored procedure can be called by multiple nodes in an environment and I don't want them to fetch duplicate data. So, I want to lock the stored procedure while it is executing and set the status of the records obtained from the stored procedure to 'In Progress' and return that table and then release the lock, so that different nodes don't fetch the same data. How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use select with `WITH (SERIALIZABLE)` isolation level to make sure that the records are locked till the status gets updated like following.

```
SELECT TOP 100 id 
INTO   #temp 
FROM   [your_table] WITH (serializable) 
WHERE  status = 'na' 

UPDATE ut 
SET    status = 'In Progress' 
FROM   [your_table] ut WITH (serializable) 
       INNER JOIN #temp T 
               ON T.id = ut.id
```

`SERIALIZABLE` Isolation Level Specifies the following:

- Statements cannot read data that has been modified but not yet
  committed by other transactions.
- No other transactions can modify data that has been read by the
  current transaction until the current transaction completes.
- Other transactions cannot insert new rows with key values that would
  fall in the range of keys read by any statements in the current
  transaction until the current transaction completes.

[**Source (MSDN)**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-transaction-isolation-level-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: UPDATE ut...what is ut here?

Comment: ut is the alias name of your table used for update.

Comment: if there are two tables, shall I use "from table1, table2 with serializable"? Is that the correct format for applying the same if records are fetched from two tables

Comment: from table1 WITH (serializable) , table2 WITH (serializable) . Better use joins